# Somando positivos num intervalo usando apenas while

Tags: python, algoritmo, while

Preciso escrever um programa utilizando laço (`while`) que receba dois números como entrada, podendo ser positivos ou negativos e não necessariamente em ordem crescente, e o programa deve imprimir a soma de todos os números positivos naquele intervalo. Comecei o código criando uma lista com todos os valores do intervalo, e preciso somar os valores positivos. Como proceder? Existe uma forma melhor que não seja criando uma lista?

```
a = int(raw_input())
b = int(raw_input())
if a < b:
    a,b = b,a
if b < a:
    a,b = b,a
y = range(a, b + 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acho que não tem forma mais simples e legível do que usar a função `sum`, já que ela foi feita para isso.

```
a = int(raw_input())
b = int(raw_input())

soma = 0

if a < b:
    soma = sum([numero for numero in range(a, b + 1) if numero > 0])
else:
    soma = sum([numero for numero in range(b, a + 1) if numero > 0])
```

Eu usei uma *list comprehension* aqui. Basicamente, estou dizendo "a soma de todos os números no intervalo maiores do que 0".

Sem usar `sum` e `for`, você pode resolver assim:

```
a = int(raw_input())
b = int(raw_input())
menor = a
maior = b

if a > b:
    menor = b
    maior = a

soma = 0

i = menor
while i <= maior:
    if i > 0:
        soma += i
    i += 1
```

Comment: Eu pensei em utilizar 'sum' no código que escrevi, mas preciso somar apenas os valores maiores que 0, utilizando laço ('while')

Comment: Desculpe. Não li direito. Estou editando.

Comment: O que siginifica '+='?

Comment: `x += y` é uma forma mais curta de escrever `x = x + y` . Pode trocar pela forma mais extensa caso achar mais claro.

Comment: Entendi. Não sabia que podia escrever a linha de código colocando a função condicional no fim, ou já tinha visto e não prestei atenção ao detalhe. Obrigado!

Comment: De qual parte especificamente você está falando?

Comment: soma = sum([numero for numero in range(a, b + 1) if numero > 0])

Comment: Isso é uma sintaxe especial. O que vem dentro das chaves é uma _list comprehension_ . É uma expressão que gera uma nova lista transformando os elementos de outra. Você pode aplicar essa transformação apenas em elementos que satisfazem uma condição-- pra isso o `if`, que tem que vir no final . Leia mais a respeito quando tiver tempo. É uma ferramenta muito legal de Python para deixar seu código mais simples.

Comment: De fato, facilita bastante. Obrigado!